# How to deploy War file in Fuse ESB

Tags: web-services, cxf, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I have developed a web service using Apache CXF and deployed it on Apache Tomcat and its working fine.

Now I required to deploy it on JBoss Fuse ESB (jboss-fuse-6.0.0). I tried to deploy it by copying it in the deploy folder but was not able to get the WSDL definition with `?wsdl` and found following error in `fuse.log`:

```
16:28:49,889 | ERROR | Executor: 1      | ContextLoader                    | 174 - org.springframework.web - 3.1.3.RELEASE | Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/cxf-beans.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws] does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)[105:org.springframework.beans:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)[105:org.springframework.beans:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)[105:org.springframework.beans:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)[105:org.springframework.beans:3.1.3.RELEASE]
```

Find below `cxf-bean.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schema/jaxws.xsd
    ">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />

    <jaxws:endpoint id="hellows" implementor="com.irk.test.ws.HelloWsImpl" address="/hellows"/>

</beans>
```

Please help me understand how I can deploy it on Fuse ESB and what kind of configuration changes required.

Comment: Which version of Fuse are you using? Which version of CXF are you compiling against? Are you providing the CXF jars in your deployment artifact or are you depending on the container to provide them?

Comment: I am using jboss-fuse-6.0.0.redhat-024

Comment: It looks to be CXF config issue. Could you plese post cxf-beans.xml config here.

Comment: Hi i have updated my post with cxf-beans.xml, but i would like to highlight that its working fine on Apache Tomcat

Comment: Same question posted here with link to answer: https://community.jboss.org/thread/232418